# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token exception after bundle two CSS file in MVC4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, optimization, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

In my MVC4 project I bundle two css file. When browse render this file then I got two exception.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I wrote this code for bundling my CSS files.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
    .Include("~/Content/css3.css","~/Content/styles.css"));
}
```

I call this in my _Layout.chshtml page.

```
<head>
   @Scripts.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
```

and get that exception.

But if I call those CSS files this way then every thing works fine.

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/css3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Here is a screen shoot of my Error.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's because it's rendering a `<script>` tag. It should be `@Styles.Render` instead of `@Scripts.Render`.

Comment: This happened for me when I had a call to @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom") in my view that didn't have a corresponding ScriptBundle setup in the BundleConfig.cs file.